# Insert image link in Excel

Tags: python, excel, image, url, openpyxl

When you want to insert an image in Excel, you would simply go to the "insert" tab, click "image", and then choose an image from your machine. However, the alternative is to type a URL into the text box, and then Word/Excel/whatever Office document you're using will know to attempt to contact that URL and download the image.

The trouble is: I need to do this programmatically. I need to use Python and I'm using openpyxl. I can't find any functionality for this in openpyxl and definitely not in vanilla Python.

Does anyone have suggestions for how I might accomplish this?

I've been all over the web and this doesn't seem to be a topic that's talked about often. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Have you looked at xlsxwriter? http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_images.html

Comment: This is covered in the documentation: http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#inserting-an-image

Comment: @bernie Thanks to both of you! I'm trying out xlsx writer and it seems to be effective!

Comment: @Charlie Clark I've read that article, but does that particular module support remotely loaded images?